# How to duplicate screen on a secondary monitor in Phoenix OS?

Tags: external-display, phoenix-os

I usually use my laptop as a CPU. I put it aside and it is connected to a screen via a VGA cable. Recently, I installed Phoenix OS in my laptop,  but nothing was displayed on my secondary monitor. In windows 10, I only have to press "Windows + P" to see split screen option, but in this OS I couldn't find such settings.

How to get that setting?

Answer (score 3):

Replace with this command on `grub.cfg`
(if dual boot with Windows 10, then search how to edit `grub.cfg` on Windows 10):

```
menuentry 'Phoenix OS--ext display' --class android-x86 {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --file --set=root /EFI/PhoenixOS/kernel
    linux /EFI/PhoenixOS/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.hardware=android_x86 SRC=/PhoenixOS vga=788 video=1920x1080 video=eDP-1:d
    initrd /EFI/PhoenixOS/initrd.img
}
```

where `1920x1080` is my secondary display resolution, `eDP` is my laptop screen, and `-1` disables it. In your case, it may be `LVDS-1:d`. Try to add both.

Comment: Just assign a drive letter to your boot drive using disk manager or any other free partition wizard software. and navigate with windows Explorer.and remove drive letter after all done (use explorer ++)